# Multiply two cells in my HTML table and automatically put the result in the third with javascript. Withot Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I want the last column where it says "Total" to multiply the quantity of a product by its price and put it in the same row as the product.

This is the current appearance of my table:
[image]

This is the code that creates the table and provides you with the data.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<style>
table,
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
</style>

<body>

<div id="contact">

    <h1>Invoice</h1>

    <form action="/table.html">
        <label for="invoice_id">Invoice:</label>
        <input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice" placeholder="Enter Invoice Id" /><br>
        <button type="button" id="form_button" value="Consultar">Consultar</button>

    </form>

</div>

<table id="demo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th id="sum">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
</table>



</body>

<script>

let button = document.getElementById("form_button");
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    let id = document.getElementById("invoice_id").value;

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
                // pasarla a objeto (JSON)



                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                //var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var myObj = {
                    code: data.code,
                    date: data.date,
                    lines: []

                };

                for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
                    let tmp = data.lines[i];
                    var line = {
                        amount: tmp.amount,
                        barcode: tmp.barcode,
                        name: tmp.name,
                        description: tmp.description,
                        price: tmp.price
                    };
                    myObj.lines[i] = line;
                }

                console.log(myObj);

                let table = document.getElementById('matchData'), sumVal = 0;
                let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
                let row = document.createElement("tr");

                for (let key in myObj) {
                    if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");

                        cell.rowSpan = line_count;
                        cell.textContent = myObj[key];
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                    if (key == "lines") {
                        for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
                            let cell = document.createElement("td");

                            cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                            row.appendChild(cell);



                        }
                        table.appendChild(row);

                        for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
                            let row = document.createElement("tr");

                            for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                                cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                                row.appendChild(cell);
                            }

                            table.appendChild(row);
                        }

                    }



                }


            } else {
                console.log("Error loading page\n");
            }
        }

    });
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
        id);

    request.send();

});

</script>

</html>
```

I've been trying various options but I can't get it to work, any ideas? Thanks.

ANNOTATION:

This is what you wanted to see?
[image]

I hope you see it well this way:

```
{"code":"Fact003","date":"2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z","lines": 
[{"amount":2,"barcode":"6854952135","name":"Teclado 
Logitech","description":"Teclado Logitech Gaming","price":45}, 
{"amount":5,"barcode":"9465986321","name":"Monitor HP 
27f","description":"Monitor de 27\" HD","price":200}, 
{"amount":3,"barcode":"5216854935","name":"Ratón 
Logitech","description":"Ratón Logitech Gaming","price":50}]}
```

ANNOTATION 2:

This is how my table looks now:

[image]

What I want is to sum the total of all the products and insert it in the cell below and next to TOTAL. Here is the new code that doesn't change much from the old one but a few things do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css">
</head>



<script>
function fetchID() {
    let Id = window.location.search.split('=')[1];
    loadTable(Id);
}
function loadTable(id) {

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
                // pasarla a objeto (JSON)

                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var myObj = {
                    code: data.code,
                    date: data.date,
                    lines: []

                };

                for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
                    let tmp = data.lines[i];
                    var line = {
                        amount: tmp.amount,
                        barcode: tmp.barcode,
                        name: tmp.name,
                        description: tmp.description,
                        price: tmp.price
                    };
                    myObj.lines[i] = line;
                }

                document.getElementById("iddate").innerHTML = data.date;
                document.getElementById("idcode").innerHTML = data.code;

                console.log(myObj);

                let table = document.getElementById('matchData'),
                    sumVal = 0;
                let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
                let row = document.createElement("tr");

                for (let key in myObj) {

                    /*if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");

                        cell.rowSpan = line_count;
                        cell.textContent = myObj[key];
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }*/

                    if (key == "lines") {

                        let price = 0,
                            amount = 0;
                        for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
                            if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                            if (line_key == 'amount') amount = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                            let cell = document.createElement("td");

                            cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                        }

                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        cell.textContent = price * amount;
                        row.appendChild(cell);

                        table.appendChild(row);

                        for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
                            let row = document.createElement("tr");
                            let _price = 0,
                                _amount = 0;
                            for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                                if (line_key == 'price') _price = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                                if (line_key == 'amount') _amount = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                                cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                                row.appendChild(cell);
                            }

                            let _cell = document.createElement("td");
                            _cell.textContent = _price * _amount;
                            row.appendChild(_cell);
                            table.appendChild(row);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                console.log("Error loading page\n");
            }
        }

    });
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
        id);

    request.send();
}
</script>


<body onload="fetchID()">

<div class="date-div" id="iddate"></div>
<div id="idcode"></div>

<table id="demo">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th id="sum">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Total</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what error (if any) have you observed would help understand better.
If possible replicate it using http://codesandbox.io/ .

Comment: I don't remember exactly what problems I had because I have stopped for a week and didn't continue so I deleted what I did and didn't try again, what do you think would be a good way to do it?

Comment: you seem to be on the right path since you are dynamically creating td elements.
Why are you not able the generate the last column as well ?

Comment: It is in the last column where I have the problem, I do not know how to multiply the quantity and price data of each product and put the result of each product in the Total.

Comment: @Alejanro Have added a clear answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mamun's answer works. But there is a simpler way to do it since you are already dynamically adding cells.

The key to it is to create an extra cell after adding the price and amount cells.

```
let price = 0, amount = 0;
for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {

    // Check if you are currently adding the price or amount cell and store them
    if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];
    if (line_key == 'amount') amount = myObj[key][0][line_key];

    let cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
    row.appendChild(cell);
}
 
// Creating an extra column to hold the Total
let cell = document.createElement("td");
cell.textContent = price * amount;

// Add this new Total cell to the row
row.appendChild(cell);

// Then finally add the row to the table
table.appendChild(row);
```

So while you are looping and adding the price and amount cells. you can store their values in 2 variables by as `if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];`

Then once you have already built all the cells, before adding the row to the table, you can create one new cell with the value `price * amount` inside it by using our new variables. Then add this cell to the row as well and finally add the row to the table.

After that use the same logic inside the last for loop like this

```
for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    let _price = 0, _amount = 0;
    for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
        if (line_key == 'price') _price = myObj[key][i][line_key];
        if (line_key == 'amount') _amount = myObj[key][i][line_key];
        let cell = document.createElement("td");

        cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
        row.appendChild(cell);
     }

     let _cell = document.createElement("td");
     _cell.textContent = _price * _amount;
     row.appendChild(_cell);
     table.appendChild(row);
 }
```

Adding the snippet if you want to go through

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<style>
  table,
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div id="contact">

    <h1>Invoice</h1>

    <form action="/table.html">
      <label for="invoice_id">Invoice:</label>
      <input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice" placeholder="Enter Invoice Id" /><br>
      <button type="button" id="form_button" value="Consultar">Consultar</button>

    </form>

  </div>

  <table id="demo">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th id="sum">Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="matchData"></tbody>
  </table>



</body>

<script>
  let button = document.getElementById("form_button");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    let id = document.getElementById("invoice_id").value;

    // let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

    if (true) {
      if (true) {
        // console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
        // pasarla a objeto (JSON)

        const data = {
          "code": "Fact003",
          "date": "2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z",
          "lines": [{
              "amount": 2,
              "barcode": "6854952135",
              "name": "Teclado Logitech",
              "description": "Teclado Logitech Gaming",
              "price": 45
            },
            {
              "amount": 5,
              "barcode": "9465986321",
              "name": "Monitor HP 27f",
              "description": "Monitor de 27\" HD",
              "price": 200
            },
            {
              "amount": 3,
              "barcode": "5216854935",
              "name": "Ratón Logitech",
              "description": "Ratón Logitech Gaming",
              "price": 50
            }
          ]
        };

        var myObj = {
          code: data.code,
          date: data.date,
          lines: []

        };

        for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
          let tmp = data.lines[i];
          var line = {
            amount: tmp.amount,
            barcode: tmp.barcode,
            name: tmp.name,
            description: tmp.description,
            price: tmp.price
          };
          myObj.lines[i] = line;
        }

        console.log(myObj);

        let table = document.getElementById('matchData'),
          sumVal = 0;
        let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
        let row = document.createElement("tr");


        for (let key in myObj) {


          if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
            let cell = document.createElement("td");

            cell.rowSpan = line_count;
            cell.textContent = myObj[key];
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }
          if (key == "lines") {

            let price = 0,
              amount = 0;
            for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
              if (line_key == 'price') price = myObj[key][0][line_key];
              if (line_key == 'amount') amount = myObj[key][0][line_key];
              let cell = document.createElement("td");

              cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
              row.appendChild(cell);
            }

            let cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.textContent = price * amount;
            row.appendChild(cell);

            table.appendChild(row);

            for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
              let row = document.createElement("tr");
              let _price = 0,
                _amount = 0;
              for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                if (line_key == 'price') _price = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                if (line_key == 'amount') _amount = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                row.appendChild(cell);
              }

              let _cell = document.createElement("td");
              _cell.textContent = _price * _amount;
              row.appendChild(_cell);
              table.appendChild(row);
            }

          }



        }


      } else {
        console.log("Error loading page\n");
      }
    }

    // });
    // request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
    // id);

    // request.send();

  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Omg, thank you very much, it works perfectly but in my case it only shows the total of the first product, what should I change to show the total of all products? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what is happening. The code change I suggested should be automatically doing it for all products since it happening in a loop.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot in my question, is that really what you need?

Comment: @AlejandroFelipeGonzalez yes, that's what I wanted. Could you also give me your sample json data. I will try it with the data.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Basically what you were doing was creating the first row separately and then creating all the other rows after that inside a for loop.
So we would have to update the last for loop as well. 
Have pasted the code inside the answer at the end and updated the snippet

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for all your help, it works perfect, thanks for everything.

Comment: Hello again, sorry to bother you but could you help me with something else?

Comment: @AlejandroFelipeGonzalez sure, if not related to this exactly, post another question and give me the link

Comment: The question is very similar to the topic of this question, it is to obtain the total of the totals (that is, the sum of all the totals of the products) and I don't know very well how to do it, could you explain how I can do it so that I can understand it? By the way thank you very much.

Comment: Where would you want to add the total of all totals. One way to do it is to define a variable at the start of your script like `let totalOfTotals = 0` and whenever you are calculation a row total, add this `total` to `totalOfTotals`. At the end, you can create another element and use `totalOfTotals` to add content to that element.

Comment: Could you show me how? I am going to update my question at the end of the question as I updated a few things.

Comment: I have already uploaded the update of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the rows and find the amount and price columns from current row using `querySelector()` and `nth-child()` selector.

Please note that the attribute *id* must be unique in a document, you can use *class* instead.

**Demo:**

```html
<style>
table,
td,
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
</style>

<body>

<div id="contact">

    <h1>Invoice</h1>

    <form action="/table.html">
        <label for="invoice_id">Invoice:</label>
        <input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice" placeholder="Enter Invoice Id" /><br>
        <button type="button" id="form_button" value="Consultar">Consultar</button>

    </form>

</div>

<table id="demo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Barcode</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th id="sum">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="matchData">
      <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Barcode</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="sum">Total</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Barcode</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>3.5</td>
        <td class="sum">Total</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



</body>

<script>

//code to calculate total
var tableRow = document.querySelectorAll('#matchData tr');
tableRow.forEach(function(tr){
  var amount = tr.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent;
  var price = tr.querySelector('td:nth-child(7)').textContent;
  tr.querySelector('.sum').textContent = amount * price;
});


let button = document.getElementById("form_button");
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    let id = document.getElementById("invoice_id").value;

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText); // datos de la factura
                // pasarla a objeto (JSON)



                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                //var myObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                var myObj = {
                    code: data.code,
                    date: data.date,
                    lines: []

                };

                for (let i = 0; i < data.lines.length; ++i) {
                    let tmp = data.lines[i];
                    var line = {
                        amount: tmp.amount,
                        barcode: tmp.barcode,
                        name: tmp.name,
                        description: tmp.description,
                        price: tmp.price
                    };
                    myObj.lines[i] = line;
                }

                console.log(myObj);

                let table = document.getElementById('matchData'), sumVal = 0;
                let line_count = myObj["lines"].length;
                let row = document.createElement("tr");

                for (let key in myObj) {
                    if (key == "code" || key == "date") {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");

                        cell.rowSpan = line_count;
                        cell.textContent = myObj[key];
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                    if (key == "lines") {
                        for (let line_key in myObj[key][0]) {
                            let cell = document.createElement("td");

                            cell.textContent = myObj[key][0][line_key];
                            row.appendChild(cell);



                        }
                        table.appendChild(row);

                        for (let i = 1; i < line_count; i++) {
                            let row = document.createElement("tr");

                            for (let line_key in myObj[key][i]) {
                                let cell = document.createElement("td");

                                cell.textContent = myObj[key][i][line_key];
                                row.appendChild(cell);
                            }

                            table.appendChild(row);
                        }

                    }



                }


            } else {
                console.log("Error loading page\n");
            }
        }

    });
    request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/invoice/" +
        id);

    request.send();

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will stick with the answer above as it is more comfortable for my example but yours also works, thanks.